# How to debug the MySQL error message: Caught an exception while rendering

Tags: python, mysql, django, dreamhost

I am building Django +MySQL on dreamhost, but met the error messages: 
Caught an exception while rendering: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ORDER BY `tag`.`used_count` DESC, `tag`.`name` ASC' at line 1")

I traced hard and found the error splot is with the function below:
Can you someone help me check what's wrong with this code?

```
 def get_tags_by_questions(self, questions):
    question_ids = []
    for question in questions:
        question_ids.append(question.id)

    question_ids_str = ','.join([force_unicode(id) for id in question_ids])
    related_tags = self.extra(
            tables=['tag', 'question_tags'],
            where=["tag.id = question_tags.tag_id AND question_tags.question_id IN (" + question_ids_str + ")"]
    ).distinct()

    return related_tags
```

Comment: Why aren't you using Django's ORM? By using it, you would automatically benefit from its abstraction, without having to care about any those SQL details.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that there are no questions, in which case the SQL will contain something like `"WHERE question_id IN ()"` which wouldn't be valid SQL.